# R lazy evaluation of two variables in data.frame

Tags: r, eval, lazy-evaluation

Given a data frame

```
df <- data.frame(a = sample(c(1,0), 30, replace = TRUE),
             b = sample(c(2,3), 30, replace = TRUE),
             c = sample(c(4,5), 30, replace = TRUE))
```

and an expression captured by the `lazy()` argument in the `lazyeval` package

```
library(lazyeval)
toeval <- lazy(c(a,b))
```

I want to get a data frame with those two variables a and b instead of one concatenated vector, as given with

```
result <- lazy_eval(toeval, df)
```

An unelegant version instantly comes to ones mind

```
df_result <- data.frame(a = result[1:(nrow(df))],
                        b = result[(nrow(df)+1):(nrow(df)*2)])
```

Better ideas are very much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
toeval <- lazy(list(a,b))
data.frame(do.call(cbind, lazy_eval(toeval, df)))
```